# Rules across specific columns

Tags: tables, rules

I would like to create a table like which looks like this:

[image]

I'm unable to insert the lines for headings properly still. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,conference]{IEEEtran}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{Time taken for full encryption/decryption using different crypto algorithms}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|*{7}{c|}}
\hline
\textbf{CPU}  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Encryption}} & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\textbf{Decryption}}
\\\textbf{Time}
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{} &\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{}
\\\textbf{(seconds)}
& \textbf{\textit{TLS}} & \textbf{\textit{CTR}} & \textbf{\textit{CBC}} & \textbf{\textit{TLS}} & \textbf{\textit{CTR}} & \textbf{\textit{CBC}}\\ \hline
Minimum & 2.2612 & 1.4145 & 2.0110 & 2.1037 & 1.4267 & 1.4002\\ \hline
Maximum & 3.0849 & 1.4156 & 2.0232 & 2.7585 & 1.4339 & 1.4059\\ \hline
Average & 2.6684 & 1.4150 & 2.0154 & 2.4186 & 1.4324 & 1.4026\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

This generates the following table:

[image]

Can you tell me how to insert that missing line?

Comment: Simply `\cline[2-7]`.

Answer (score 3):

To insert lines that span columns from column `<a>` to column `<b>`, you can use `\cline{<a>-<b>}`. I'd suggest using [`booktabs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) though:

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,conference]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \caption{Time taken for full encryption/decryption using different crypto algorithms}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{|*{7}{c|}}
    \hline
    \textbf{CPU}  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{} & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{} \\
    \textbf{Time} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Encryption}} &\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\textbf{Decryption}} \\
    \cline{2-7}
    \textbf{(seconds)} & \textbf{\textit{TLS}} & \textbf{\textit{CTR}} & \textbf{\textit{CBC}} & \textbf{\textit{TLS}} & \textbf{\textit{CTR}} & \textbf{\textit{CBC}} \\
    \hline
    Minimum & 2.2612 & 1.4145 & 2.0110 & 2.1037 & 1.4267 & 1.4002 \\
    \hline
    Maximum & 3.0849 & 1.4156 & 2.0232 & 2.7585 & 1.4339 & 1.4059 \\
    \hline
    Average & 2.6684 & 1.4150 & 2.0154 & 2.4186 & 1.4324 & 1.4026 \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
  \caption{Time taken for full encryption/decryption using different crypto algorithms}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{ *{7}{c} }
    \toprule
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Encryption}} &\multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Decryption}} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-4}\cmidrule(lr){5-7}
    \raisebox{\dimexpr1.25\normalbaselineskip-.5\height}[0pt][0pt]{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
      \textbf{CPU time} \\ \textbf{(seconds)}
    \end{tabular}} & \textbf{\textit{TLS}} & \textbf{\textit{CTR}} & \textbf{\textit{CBC}} & \textbf{\textit{TLS}} & \textbf{\textit{CTR}} & \textbf{\textit{CBC}} \\
    \midrule
    Minimum & 2.2612 & 1.4145 & 2.0110 & 2.1037 & 1.4267 & 1.4002 \\
    Maximum & 3.0849 & 1.4156 & 2.0232 & 2.7585 & 1.4339 & 1.4059 \\
    Average & 2.6684 & 1.4150 & 2.0154 & 2.4186 & 1.4324 & 1.4026 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach that complements @Werner's second solution. I would like to recommend that you get rid of the unnecessary (and borderline vulgar-looking) **bold** and *italics* in the header cells. With a well-structured header, using bold and italics shouldn't be needed at all. Separately, to assure that the table will automatically span the full width of the column, you may want to use a `tabular*` environment instead of the `tabular` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % let tabular* figure out intercolumn whitespace
\caption{CPU time taken for full encryption/decryption using different crypto algorithms}
\begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}l*{6}{c}}
\toprule
CPU Time  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Encryption} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Decryption}\\
\cmidrule{2-4} \cmidrule{5-7}
(seconds)
& TLS & CTR & CBC & TLS & CTR & CBC\\ 
\midrule
Minimum & 2.2612 & 1.4145 & 2.0110 & 2.1037 & 1.4267 & 1.4002\\ 
Maximum & 3.0849 & 1.4156 & 2.0232 & 2.7585 & 1.4339 & 1.4059\\ 
Average & 2.6684 & 1.4150 & 2.0154 & 2.4186 & 1.4324 & 1.4026\\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```